# Split the string in a certain way

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a string:

```
50 5 10 4 48 34
```

Where each value corresponds to the following notation scheme:

```
x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3
```

that is, it means that:

```
x1 = 50
y1 = 5
etc.
```

At the input, a numeric string separated by spaces is written to my variable, I want to get a list from it, in which tuples storing coordinates are written comma-separated, that is:

```
[(50, 5), (10, 4), (48, 34)]
```

please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
input_string = "50 5 10 4 48 34"
numeric_values = input_string.split()  

coordinates = [(int(numeric_values[i]), int(numeric_values[i + 1])) for i in range(0, len(numeric_values), 2)]
print(coordinates)
```

Comment: if you check the code that you wrote, there will be an error: list index out of range

Comment: Are you sure? It works just fine for me.

Comment: works fine for me I get the output ```[(50, 5), (10, 4), (48, 34)]```

please check thoroughly, could you please provide the full error detials

Comment: However, if in a loop, in the range sequence generator, replace the order of values with the correct one. generation starts from 0 in increments of 2, up to the value of the row size. Then you will get this result: [(50, 5)]

Comment: This is a good answer, I'm a little confused in my code @AliciaStone

Answer (score 1):

Starting with python 3.12, you can use the [`itertools.batched`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched) method on the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) string:

```
from itertools import batched

s = '50 5 10 4 48 34'
out = list(batched(map(int, s.split()), 2))
```

For previous versions, this iterator trick is always working:

```
s = '50 5 10 4 48 34'

i = map(int, s.split())
out = list(zip(i, i))

# or as a one-liner for python ≥ 3.8
out = list(zip((i:=map(int, s.split())), i))
```

Output: `[(50, 5), (10, 4), (48, 34)]`